# Unable to reference object with 2d vector member

Tags: c++, class, vector, scope

So I have a class `Board` with a 2d vector member `kBoard`.  I'm trying access the elements of `kBoard` using `std::vector::at()`
I've created the object like this:

```
Board * board = new Board();
```

Then, I access the member in this way:

```
board->kBoard.at(pos0).at(pos1);
```

Here, pos0 and pos1  are integers.
The compiler is telling me that `left of .at must have class/struct/union, type is std::vector<_Ty> [8][8], with _Ty = int`

Here are my files defining `class Board`:
**Board.cpp**

```
#include "Board.h"
Board::Board(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            kBoard[i][j].assign(1,-1);
        }
    }
}


Board::~Board(void)
{}
```

**Board.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
class Board
{
public:
    Board(void);
    std::vector<int> kBoard[8][8];
    ~Board(void);
};
```

Now, I wasn't having trouble when I had `kBoard` defined as an integer array, but I decided to make it a `std::vector<int>` when I realized that, if I wanted bound-checking, which I do, I would need the `at()` function from `std::vector`.

This all looks correct to me, so I'm also going to paste my main .cpp file in its entirety, in case the error actually stems from some other place in my code. Keep in mind that this code doesn't really do anything as is, I just want to fix errors before I try to write the rest of my code.
**Knightstour.cpp**

```
#include    "KnightsTour.h"
void main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int xPos, yPos, pos1 = 0, pos0 = 0;
    Board * board = new Board;
    board->kBoard.at(pos0).at(pos1); //issue here
    forward_list<Knight> * route = new forward_list<Knight>;
    route->emplace_front();
    cout << "Knight's starting x position: "; cin >> xPos; xPos -= 1;
    cout << "Knight's starting y position: "; cin >> yPos; yPos -= 1;
    route->begin()->setPos(xPos, yPos);
    route->begin()->setMoves();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        pos0 = route->begin()->moves[i].at(0);
        pos1 = route->begin()->moves[i].at(1);
        if(board->kBoard.at(pos0).at(pos1)) //issue here
            ;
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete route;
    delete board;
    return;
}
```

**KnightsTour.h**

```
#pragma once
#include    <iostream>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stack>
#include    <forward_list>
#include    "Board.h"
#include    "Knight.h"
```

Comment: `std::vector<int> kBoard[8][8]` is not a 2d vector.  It is a 2d array of vectors.  A 2d vector looks like `std::vector<std::vector<some_type> some_name`

Comment: OHHHHHH ok! That's pretty obvious, now that I think about it!

Comment: Unrelated: We don't have a full example, but you may be able to replace `Board * board = new Board();` with `Board board;` (swap a dynamic allocation for an Automatic one) and pick up fewer memory management responsibilities.

Comment: ^^ also applies to route. If the scope of an object is inside the method just put it on the stack. (IE automatic duration)

Edit* Also anytime you use `.at()` you can just use the `operator[int index]` (unless you really want boundary checks, but if you know it will succeed you get a bit of a performance boost + clearer code)

Comment: That actually is a really helpful tip! Of course, it's important to note that, when using objects in that way, you must use `obj.func()` instead of `obj.func()`  
As for using `.at()`, I am using that for boundary-checks, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually missed the correct implementation of a 2d vector.
A 2d vector, like the comment from @NathanOliver shows, is instantiated thus:
`std::vector<std::vector<type>> name`
What I made was a 2d array of vectors.